# login authentication in asp.net 2.0

Tags: asp.net-2.0

i am working on asp.net 2.0 and sql server 2005 
i am using login authentication 
where userid = CJ
and password = 123 
when i click on login button  the text welcome CJ must be displayed. on redirected page 
any help will be welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If your user is valid store it in a
>   session :

```
MyUser currentUser = UserLogin(userName, password);
if(currentUser!=null){
    Session["loggedUser"] = current;
    Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
}
else
{
  //User authentication failed
}
```

> When you access the logged user check
>   if the session variable is null :

```
if(Session["loggedUser"]!=null)
{
   MyUser currentUser = (MyUser)Session["loggedUser"];
}
```

> When you click the logout button clean
>   your session variable (inside your Logout method) :

```
Session["loggedUser"] = null;
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Store your user data in a session after the user was validated, and clean the session on logout. Storing you logged user in a session you can access you user from any page.